# How to fix Missing Message-ID in zend-mail

Tags: php, zend-mail

I try to use zend-mail. I can send an email, but zend-mail didn't generate the message-id automatically, so I get this `Message-Id`:

```
<1xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxSMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
```

when I check the original message.

so I've searched on Google & Zend-mail page and GitHub, but can't find how to add the `message-id`.

I tried this code to set the `message-id`:

```
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Header/MessageId.php');
use Zend\Mail\Header\MessageId;

$messid = new MessageId();
$messid->setId();
```

but still no `message-id`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getId()` method see the method here in the source code. https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mail/blob/master/src/Header/MessageId.php#L88

this will return the id

```php
$messid->getId();
```

Comment: i get the message-id

Comment: but when i check in original message, still SMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com

Comment: what transport you use in order to send?

Comment: i use smtp transport

Comment: @AligaMyway did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same an due to that i think DKIM fails...

Comment: I've solved this problem, first, i need to clearallheaders like this 
$message = new Message();
$message->getHeaders()->clearHeaders();
and set message-id after that

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem, first, i need to clearallheaders like this

```
$message = new Message(); 
$message->getHeaders()->clearHeaders();
```

and set message-id after that